# AsyncTask crashes when used from onSurfaceCreated

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I have a class that extends GLSurfaceView and implements Renderer in my android app that takes care of the opengl rendering.  When I try to execute an asynctask from the onSurfaceCreated event, the application crashes (no exceptions thrown).  If run the same async task from the main activity everything is fine.  The asynctask implementation is at this point just a place holder:

```
public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer>
{
        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... myParams) {
            return 1;
         }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result)
        {

        }
     }
```

being called from onSurfaceCreated()

```
new DownloadImageTask().execute("myParam");
```

Why can't I start an AsyncTask from the onSurfaceCreated event?

Comment: Paste the logcat output after the app crash.

Comment: Stole, I added the calling code to the question.

Comment: Christian, where does one find logcat output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to call it on the UI thread. Try passing in the context and do runOnUIThread.

Comment: Is there a way to know if your code is running on the UI thread or not?

Comment: There is a way in swing, I am not sure about android. I googled a bit but i couldn't find anything. But i don't think anything would go wrong if you always call runOnUIThread.